# Abbreviations are replaced more than once: iaw --> in accordance with --> input accordance with

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am dealing with a dataframe that contains a lot of abbreviations in columns of text. With a predefined dictionary, I am replacing the abbreviations with their full words and this works.

But the abbreviations seem to be replaced more than once. If the full word that replaces the abbreviation contains another abbreviation, this abbreviation is replaced again:

```
d = {' h ' : ' height ', ' mm ' : ' milimeter ', ' w ' : 'width', ' iaw ' : ' in accordance with ', ' in ' : ' input '}

dt = {"Number":[1, 2], "text": ["measure depth 22 mm h 24 mm w 75 mm", "wheel 4 iaw amm"]}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dt) 

def process_data(file_name):
  data = file_name
  data["text"].replace(d, regex=True, inplace=True)
  return data

df = process_data(dataframe)
print(df)
```

The result of this is:

```
   Number                                                 text
0  1       measure depth 22 milimeter height 24 milimeter w 75 mm
1  2       wheel 4 input accordance with amm
```

While it should be:

```
   Number                                                 text
0  1       measure depth 22 milimeter height 24 milimeter w 75 mm
1  2       wheel 4 in accordance with amm
```

Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `regex`:

```
#removed whitespaces
d = {'h' : 'height', 
     'mm' : 'milimeter', 
     'w' : 'width',
     'iaw' : 'in accordance with',
     'in' : 'input'}


pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in d.keys())
dataframe['keyword'] = dataframe['text'].str.replace(pat, lambda x: d[x.group()], regex=True)
print (dataframe)

   Number                                 text  \
0       1  measure depth 22 mm h 24 mm w 75 mm   
1       2                      wheel 4 iaw amm   

                                             keyword  
0  measure depth 22 milimeter height 24 milimeter...  
1                     wheel 4 in accordance with amm
```

Another solution is split values by whitespaces, map by dictionary with `get` and `join` back by `space`:

```
f = lambda x: ' '.join(d.get(y, y) for y in x.split())
dataframe['keyword'] = dataframe['text'].apply(f)
print (dataframe)
   Number                                 text  \
0       1  measure depth 22 mm h 24 mm w 75 mm   
1       2                      wheel 4 iaw amm   

                                             keyword  
0  measure depth 22 milimeter height 24 milimeter...  
1                     wheel 4 in accordance with amm
```

Comment: @Wen-Ben - yes, just realised it. I think is necessary change dictionary for correct output